# Bug in `forfiles`, wrong expansion of `@file` variable?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Using the `forfiles` batch command, sometimes the `@path` variable and the `@file` variable are the same, and sometimes they are different.  This looks like a bug to me.

To illustrate - setup:

```
md test_subfolder
echo Hello>test_subfolder\test.txt
```

Now `@path` and `@file` are different, like you would expect:

```
forfiles /p test_subfolder /c "cmd /c echo CD: [%cd%] PATH: [@path] FILE: [@file]"
```

That yields:

```
CD: [D:\] PATH: ["D:\test_subfolder\test.txt"] FILE: ["test.txt"]
```

Now, try overwriting the file using `@path`.  This does what you would expect.

```
forfiles /p test_subfolder /c "cmd /c echo Goodbye>@path"
type test_subfolder\test.txt
```

Result:

```
Goodbye
```

Trying the same thing using `@file` instead of `@path`:

```
forfiles /p test_subfolder /c "cmd /c echo Farewell>@file"
```

This *should* create a new file in the root, and leave the file in the subfolder unchanged.  But instead, it behaves the same way that the `@path` does.
Checking for the file in the root folder:

```
dir test.txt
```

Result:

```
 Volume in drive D is Recovery
 Volume Serial Number is AE9D-4134

 Directory of D:\

File Not Found
```

Looking in the subfolder:

```
type test_subfolder\test.txt
```

Result:

```
Farewell
```

This is using Windows 7 Professional - I don't know how it might work in other versions.

How can I get `@file` to behave the way I expect?

Comment: where are your actually executing the script from ? path ? , because "path" will give the whole file path with name and file would only give you "file" name

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a bug. The real problem is the point where the parser expands `%CD%`, it is done *immediately*, so you see the current directory of the `cmd` instance you are working in.

The `cmd` instance opened by `forfiles` receives the path provided at `/p` as the current directory. To see this, change the command line to:

```
forfiles /p test_subfolder /c "cmd /c echo CD: [0x25cd0x25] PATH: [@path] FILE: [@file]"
```

`0x25` represents the hex. code of the `%` sign, so expansion of `%cd%` is not done immediately, but transferred to the "inner" `cmd` instance.

This will show you that the `echo` command is actually executed in `D:\test_subfolder` and so the `@file` variable expansion of `forfiles` behaves correctly. Hence the output will be:

```
CD: [D:\test_subfolder] PATH: ["D:\test_subfolder\test.txt"] FILE: ["test.txt"]
```

---

This explains why your line of code `forfiles /p test_subfolder /c "cmd /c echo Farewell>@file"`, when executed in `D:\`, (over-)writes the file `D:\test_subfolder\test.txt` rather than creating a new file `D:\test.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Hm ... this works!  It's a mystery to me why, though.

```
forfiles /p test_subfolder /c "cmd /c echo So Long>%CD%@file"
type test.txt
```

Result:

```
So Long
```

Answer (score 0):

`forfiles /p test_subfolder /c "cmd /c echo So Long>%CD%\@file"` command is working for me,**[please note that i have used "\" after %CD%]** , you need write to a file in the sub directory , you are trying to execute the above command outside the sub folder , probabaly that might me the reason you are feeling the difference between @path and @file